# How can i get all html element from ascx in ascx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

The html code is auto generate by my ascx.cs page_load event part.

Then, I want to get the directly html element's value to save. So How can i do

this. The html code is haven't the attribute(runat).

This is a example about my Html code generate.

```c#
function genWorkOpinion(UserId) {
    var col;
    var tta;
    var Label;
    var now = new Date();
    var id = now.getHours().toString() + now.getMinutes() + now.getSeconds() + now.getMilliseconds();

    var bossCount = 0;

    col = window.jQuery("<div class='col-md-12'>");
    Label = window.jQuery("<Label>").text("SomeText");
    tta = window.jQuery("<textarea id='" + id + "'>").attr("style", "width:100%; height:100px");
    col.append(Label);
    col.append(tta);
    window.jQuery("#workOpinion").append(col);
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear , whether your html is render successfully on ascx or not ? if yes what you want next ?

Comment: html render successfully on ascx.
But i want to get the html element value from ascx in ascx.cs

Answer (score 0):

you should add a name attribute to your input tag or any html element, example:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
```

then you can get it in code behinde as:

```
 if (IsPostBack)
 {
   nameBox = Request.Form["name"];
   Response.Write("Name: " + nameBox);
 }
```

Comment: If the id is generate by the time(now).How can find it

Comment: if helpfull for you please vote and accept the answer , make helpfull for other